# AS3 Passing Variable Parameters to a generic Function Menu / SubItems

Tags: actionscript-3, events, variables, drop-down-menu, parameter-passing

I'm no code genius, but a fan of action script.
Can you help me on this:

I have a function that depending on the object selected, will call event listeners to a set of 'sub-items' that are already on stage (I want to reuse this subitems with changed parameters upon click, instead of creating several instances and several code).

So for each selected 'case' I have to pass diferent variables to those 'sub-items', like this:

```
function fooMenu(event:MouseEvent):void {
    switch (event.currentTarget.name)
    {
        case "btUa1" :
            trace(event.currentTarget.name);
            // a bunch of code goes here
            //(just cleaned to easy the view)
            /*
            HELP HERE <--
            here is a way to pass the variables to those subitems
            */

            break;
    }
}

function fooSub(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(event.target.data);
    trace(event.currentTarget.name);
    // HELP PLEASE <-> How can I access the variables that I need here ?
}

btUa1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fooMenu);
btUa2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fooMenu);

btTextos.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fooSub);
btLegislacao.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fooSub);
```

Anyone to help me please?
Thank very much in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm not sure I got your question right, and I haven't developed in AS3 for a while.)

If you want to simply create function with parameters which will be called upon a click (or other event) you can simply use this:

```
btUa1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function() {
  fooMenu(parameters);
});

btUa2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function() {
  fooMenu(other_parameters)
}):

public function fooMenu(...rest):void {
  for(var i:uint = 0; i < rest.length; i++)
  {
     // creating elements
  }
}
```

If you want to call event listeners assigned to something else you can use DispatchEvent

```
btnTextos.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK))
```

---

Remember, you can't use btTextos.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, carregaConteudo("jocasta")); because the 2nd parameter you pass while adding Eventlistener will be considered as function itself - there are two proper ways to use addEventListener:

1:

```
function doSomething(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  // function code
}
element.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doSomething); //notice no brackets
```

2:

```
element.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function() { // function code });
```

So:

```
function fooSub(event:MouseEvent, bla:String):void 
{ 
trace(event.currentTarget.name+" - "+bla); 
// bla would be a clip name. 
} 

codebtTextos.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent) { fooSub(e, "jocasta") } );
```

---

Or try something like this if you want content to be dynamically generated:

```
btUa1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function() {
    createMenu(1);
});

btUa2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function() {
    createMenu(2);
});

function createMenu(id):void
{
    // Switching submenu elements
    switch (id)
    {
        case 1:
            createSubmenu([myFunc1, myFunc2, myFunc3]); // dynamically creating submenus in case you need more of them than u already have
            break;
        case 2:
            createSubmenu([myFunc4, myFunc5, myFunc6, myFunc7]);
            break;
        default:
            [ and so on ..]
    }
}

function createSubmenu(...rest):void {
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < rest.length; i++) 
    {
        var mc:SubItem = new SubItem(); // Subitem should be an MovieClip in library exported for ActionScript
        mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rest[i] as function)
        mc.x = i * 100;
        mc.y = 0;
        this.addChild(mc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks !!!
Here to clear what I need:

in my stage I have 6 items-object and 3 subitems-object
when click on item (fooMenu) I rearrange those 3 subitems, and need to give those 3 new click event parameters (so they can call new clips when clicked).

I tried your explanation, but didn't get it right... here:
`code`
function fooSub(event:MouseEvent, bla:String):void
{
 trace(event.currentTarget.name+" - "+bla);
    // bla would be a clip name.
}

in fooMenu case:
`code`btTextos.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fooSub("jocasta"));

Comment: notice edited answer ;) Hope it helps. If you want to add some info to your question use comment below your question, or edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather vague; what "variables" do you want to "pass"? And what do you mean by "passing the variable to a sub item"? Usually "passing" means invoking a function.

If you can be more specific on what exactly your trying to do that would be helpful. In the meantime, here are three things that may get at what you want:

You can get any member of any object using bracket notation.

```
var mc:MovieClip = someMovieClip;  
var xVal:Number = mc.x;     // The obvious way
xVal = mc["x"];             // This works too
var propName:String = "x";
xVal = mc[propName] ;       // So does this.
```

You can refer to functions using variables

```
function echo(message:String):void { 
    trace(message); 
}
echo("Hello");                      // The normal way
var f:Function = echo; 
f("Hello");                         // This also works
```

You can call a function with all the arguments in an array using function.apply

```
// Extending the above example...
var fArgs:Array = ["Hello"];
f.apply(fArgs);    // This does the same thing
```

Between these three things (and the `rest` parameter noted by another poster) you can write some very flexible code. Dynamic code comes at a performance cost for sure, but as long as the frequency of calls is a few hundred times per second or less you'll never notice the difference.

Comment: Thanks.. great explanation, but it keeps saying 'coercion' problem.

I'm still having trouble, probably my 'logic' what I'm trying to achieve is:

in my stage I have 6 items-object and 3 subitems-object when click on item (fooMenu) I rearrange those 3 subitems, and need to give those 3 new click event parameters (so they can call new clips when clicked). I tried your explanation, but didn't get it right yet.